# How to get post ID in a Page?

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, query-posts

I'm trying to list all of my posts in a page(with post's content). Everything is showing correctly but the audio player which uses post id to get the URL of an attachment in the post is not showing. I'm using the following code to get the post ID:-

```
global $wp_query;
$postID = $wp_query->$post->ID;
$file_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, sound_s, true );
$fileUrl = wp_get_attachment_url($file_id);
$attr = array(
'src'      => $fileUrl,
'loop'     => '',
'autoplay' => '',
'preload'  => 'none'
);
echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
```

It works in the post itself but when I try to list it in the page the post ID shows page Id instead. Please help me with this.

Comment: How do you query and output the posts?

Comment: `$postID = wp_quey->post->ID;` - that's not valid PHP. Please post the code you're actually using.

Comment: @Gray sorry for the spelling mistake. But the question is still same.

Comment: `$postID = wp_query->post->ID;` is still invalid PHP and will throw a fatal error. Why don't you just post exactly what you have?

Comment: @Gray I think it's right now.

Comment: @Milo I'm using a plugin (wp show post) which uses a shortcode to show posts on pages

Comment: I don't know much about your plugin but if you get a list of posts, you could just loop over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use globals directly. There are some nice wrapper functions in the WordPress API. If you want to retrieve the ID of the current post or page just use **get_the_ID()**.

Without any test ... you could write the functionality in this way:

```
$file_id  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'sound_s', true );
$file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $file_id );

echo wp_audio_shortcode( [ 'src' => $file_url ] );
```

I don't know much about the plugin that you use but why don't you loop just over the list of posts:

```
$posts = get_posts();
foreach ( $posts as $item ) {
    $file_id  = get_post_meta( $item->ID, 'sound_s', true );
    $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $file_id );

    echo wp_audio_shortcode( [ 'src' => $file_url ] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but when I'm trying to loop through posts, It gives me the correct post ID however when trying to echo $file_url. It is showing nothing. Do anyone know why It's happening

Comment: Is there a value in $file_id?

Comment: No It's returning 0 when I'm trying to var_dump($file_id)